# Generic Function not accepting Custom RowMapper as parameter

Tags: java, postgresql, java-8, jdbctemplate

I have created a generic function for executing jdbctemplate

```
   public <T> execute(String query, Object[] params, Class<T> clazz) {
        try {
            return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query, params, clazz);
        } catch (Exception) {
            log.warn("Exception occurred while executing jdbctemplate queryForObject");
        }
    }
```

The above code works fine for

```
execute("SOME QUERY", new Object[] { 12,33 }, Integer.class);
```

But not working for custom RowMapper like for example

```
 execute("SOME QUERY", new Object[] { 44 }, new EmployeRowMapper());
```

Can someone help me on this

#### Update 1

When I have tried with

```
execute("SOME QUERY", new Object[] { 44 }, EmployeRowMapper.class);
```

I am getting the following exception

> **Incompatible types. Required Employe but 'execute' was inferred to T:**
> **no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that EmployeRowMapper**
> **conforms to Employe**

The `EmployeRowMapper` is a custom RowMapper which returns `Employe` object

#### Update 2

My `EmployeRowMapper` implementation is like this

```
@Slf4j
public class EmployeRowMapper implements RowMapper<Employe> {

    @Override
    public Employe mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) {
        try {
            return Employe.builder()
                    .name(rs.getString("employe_name"))
                    .place(rs.getString("employe_place"))
                    .status(rs.getInt("employe_status")))
                    .age(rs.getInt("employe_age")))
                    .build();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            log.warn("Exception in getting the request parameter: {}", exception.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: try using `EmployeRowMapper.class` instead?

Comment: @michalk I tried that but getting `Incompatible types. Required Employe but 'execute' was inferred to T: no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that EmployeRowMapper conforms to Employe`

Answer (score 1):

Try
`execute("SOME QUERY", new Object[] { 44 }, EmployeRowMapper.class);`

Please

Comment: when you use new, you are calling the constructor and instantiating the class

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried that but getting `Incompatible types. Required Employe but 'execute' was inferred to T: no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that EmployeRowMapper conforms to Employe`

Answer (score 1):

Your generic method `execute` requires a `Class` object as a parameter. You are passing an instance of `EmployeRowMapper` as you are calling its constructor.

You would need to pass `EmployeRowMappers` class, so pass `EmployeRowMapper.class` instead of creating and passing a new instance.

**Update**
So i looked up the documentation of [JdbcTemplate#query](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper-) which you are using. Take a look as well. You need to pass an instance of the RowMapper that should be used for creating the entity. So your `execute` method needs to declare the Entity-Type as generic and expect a `RowMapper` instnace for that type as a parameter. Like this:

```
class DBAccess{
    public <T> T execute(String query, Object[] params, RowMapper<T> mapper){
        return jdbcTemplate.query(query, params, mapper);
    }
}
```

When calling `execute`, you need to pass an instance of `EmployeRowMapper` so that it returns en `Employe` constructed by the `RowMapper` you passed.

**Note** that the method you are calling is deprecated according to its documentation. You should consider using a different `query` method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried that but getting `Incompatible types. Required Employe but 'execute' was inferred to T: no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that EmployeRowMapper conforms to Employe`

Comment: @AlexMan Im assuming the line you call `execute` in assigns its value to a variable of type `Employe` and not of type `EmployeRowMapper` ie. `Employe employe = execute("SOME QUERY", new Object[] { 44 }, EmployeRowMapper.class)`? The class you pass as a parameter to `execute` is the type `T` is assigned to. Therefore it is also the return type of your `execute` method. So if you need it to return an `Employe`, you need to pass `Employe.class`. If you want an `EmployeRowMapper` the variable you store the return value of `execute` in must be of that type and not `Employe`.

Comment: all custom RowMapper returns a different object, in my case EmployeRowMapper returns Employe,  So as per your view does that means I can't use this generic function `execute` to use for this use case

Comment: will my custom RowMapper `EmployeRowMapper` gets auto executed if I pass `Employe employe = execute("SOME QUERY", new Object[] { 44 }, Employe.class)`

Comment: No. The execution of your rowmapper is something either the framework you are using to access the database or you your self have to take care of. You'd have to query the raw data from that database. paass them to your rowmapper and parse your entity. then return it. Since you didnt tell us what frameworks you are using or how your rowmapper looks like i can't tell more than that with the information given.

Comment: I am using Spring as my base framework and uses JdbcTemplate for calling all the postgres query execution

Comment: I haven't worked with `Spring` yet so i can't tell you how their framwork operates. But unless `queryForObject` provides support of such `RowMappers`, you have to take care of the execution your self. Is that construct something self made or something out of the `Spring` framework? If `queryForObject` doesn't support it directly, Spring might be able to integrate it via Annotations. But as i said, i don't know the framework and you haven't provided us your `EployeRowMapper` class either. With this information i can only take best guesses.

Comment: I have updated my question with the `EmployeRowMapper` implementation

Comment: @AlexMan I've looked up the documentation for you and added an explanation with example. Have a look.

Comment: but then how could I use the non RowMapper option like Integer or String

Comment: Also now this generic function need to always return List. since return type of query is List https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTl22.png

Comment: You would need to create a class that implements `RowMapper<Integer>` or `RowMapper<String>`. Tho this kind of destroys the purpose of the interface. From my understanding it is meant to construct more complex objects/entities and not simple single values. The only reason why your `execute` allowed for `Integer.class` as a parameter was because the parameter wasn't specified as a RowMapper. But according to documentation there actually is not a `query` method that supports a parameter of type `Class`. So your code shouldn't even compile there.

Comment: @AlexMan Yes the query methods always provide a set of data. since it depends on the query-parameters how many rows will be in the result. This is something the framework can't possibly know, so it needs to return a List. But you may just `return list != null && !list.isEmpty() ? list.get(0) : null;` if you want to get the first entry that was in the result. This is simply how the framework you are using is built. If it doesn't suit your needs, ditch Spring. Either that or work with it the way its meant to be used.

Answer (score 0):

There are two `queryForObject` methods in the `JdbcTemplate` class. One takes a `Class`, and the other takes an instance of `RowMapper`. Now as `clazz` is obviously an instance of `Class` it's going to assume that that is the version of `queryForObject` you want to use. You get this to work for both scenarios you will need to amend your method to check if `clazz` is of type `RowMapper`:

```java
if (clazz instanceof RowMapper) {
    //cast to RowMapper and use that version of queryForObject
} else {
    //use the one your code currently uses.
}
```